# Launch a server application from browser (php)

Tags: php, macos

I'm relatively new on php, but I am currently facing a problem.

I have modified a Mac OS X to run it a server and I would like to be able to launch some apps on the server using a web browser. the final idea is to use a button and when I click on it it launches the application after a test (is the application already on?)

but first of all I have started small. I have created this html page containing a script:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
    print "hello word";
    $output=exec(" open /Applications/Cyberduck.app");
    print $output;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The script is working properly when I'm launching in on command line, but when I try to launch it from a web browser it doesn't do anything at all (except write "hello world")

I have tried to counter the problem writing a shell script launching the application, but the script runs when I launch it from web browser, but doesn't open the application.

I am sure that I am missing something quite obvious, but I haven't found any solution by looking over the internet (I can admit that I have probably a lack of vocabulary and my research terms are maybe not the relevant)

Thanks for your help,

Marc

Comment: That's because the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command executes a command on the server it's running, not the visitors computer. Otherwise it would be a huge security issue.

Comment: I don't want the application to be launched on the server not on the visitors computer. and it actually doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your webserver does not run as the same user and privileges as the GUI user.
You could solve this by using su or sudo to run as a different user. But note that with su a password input will pop up, which is hard to handle.

Alternatively you could try creating a separate script that launches Cyberduck, with it's setuid bit set. The setuid bit allows a script to be automatically run with the privileges of the owner of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, I will try it, but is safe?

Comment: The setuid bit allows you to just run that specific script as a different user. Yes, it increases the attack vector, slightly.

Comment: Moreover I am currently reading that setuid is disabled on Mac OS X 10.5, it't seems to be an extreme solution

Comment: That is quite an old operating system. You may be better off just installing linux there instead.

Then your only option is probably sudo, or by creating a deamon that runs as your own user.

Who cares about security if you're running a system that's riddled with security holes?